# php-fpm configuration : unknown entry 'access.log'

Tags: php

I'm trying to setting up two service with php-fpm / nginx on two separates containers ( back service, as an API / front service where static files are built with a bit of php ). It's a small school project I'm building with tools that I don't know, just to learn.

I'm actually trying to touch php-fpm configuration, so I created a directory near the existing one where I store my test. This directory is included, no problem, but when I try to set an access.log key, even it is copy pasted from an other file already included that works, I receive the message ' unknown entry 'access.log'' .

> [global]
>
> ; logging files
>
> error_log = /var/php-fpm/log/error.log
>
> access.log = log/$pool.access.log
>
> slowlog = /var/php-fpm/log/slow.log
>
> request_slowlog_timeout = 2s
> request_slowlog_trace_depth = 200
>
> request_terminate_timeout = 20
>
> security.limit_extensions = .php
>
> ; !important
>
> listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock

Can someone tell me where I am wrong ?

Comment: Are you try absolute path for `access.log`?

Comment: It is an old question, and I don't remember what I've done, sorry

Answer (score 5):

In your example you have the `access.log` setting under the `[global]` block

From the docs the `access.log` is a pool level config option.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php

Your example config would be something like

```
[global]

error_log = /var/php-fpm/log/error.log

 ...

[www]

access.log = log/$pool.access.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename access.log to access_log

Your exemple file looks like an nginx configuration file.

Access logging is made in nginx with

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
```

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work. The example is really for php-fpm, and is documented on php.net. http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php . It also works for some reason on an other file that is present by default in the container